# Total variation norm as an Operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact subset. Let $(C(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^k, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ be the space of continuous functions on $\Omega$ endowed with the $\infty$-norm. Then its topological dual space is given by $(\mathcal{M}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^k),\|\cdot\|_{TV})$, i.e. the space of vector valued measures with the total variation norm. Now, my question is, is if I can define the total variation norm of a measure $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^k)$ with the operator norm, i.e. something like this

$$\|\mu\|_{TV} = \sup_{\|f\|_\infty=1} \langle f,\mu \rangle.$$

Comment: You probably know this, but at least in the dimension $1$ case this is true. It's roughly the content of the [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_the_continuous_dual_of_C0(X)).

Comment: My guess is yes: A variant of the Radon-Nykodim theorem says that such a $\mu$ can be written as $d\mu(x)= g(x)d\mu_0(x)$, where $g:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $\mu$-measurable function and $\mu_0$ is a nonnegative measure, with the total variation of $\mu$ being $\| g\|_{L^1(\mu_0)}$. Then the representation that you want is a consequence of the duality between $L^1$ and $L^\infty$.

Comment: This is included in the Riesz Representation Theorem